# node/typescript: how to ensure imports with side effects are run?

Tags: node.js, typescript, decorator

I am writing a node app in typescript.  I have written a class decorator `@myDecorator`, and the purpose of `@myDecorator` is such that I need to keep track of all the classes to which it's applied.

My question: how do I make sure all of those decorated classes are loaded before making use of that behavior?  Some example code will help to make this more concrete:

1. Declaration of the decorator in file `myDecorator.ts`:

```js
type ConstructorType = { new (...args: any[]): any };

// keep track of decorated classes
const registeredClasses: Map<string, ConstructorType> = new Map();

// class decorator
export function myDecorator<T extends ConstructorType>(targetConstructor: T) {
  // create the modified class
  const newClass = class extends targetConstructor { /* ... */ }
  // register the modified class
  registeredClasses.set(targetConstructor.name, newClass);
  // and return it
  return newClass;
}

export function doSomethingWithMyDecoratedClasses() {
  //... some behavior that relies on `registeredClasses`
}
```

2. Declaration of a decorated class in file `someClass.ts`

```js
import {myDecorator} from 'myDecorator.ts'

@myDecorator
class SomeClass { /* ... */ }
```

3. Making use of `doSomethingWithMyDecoratedClasses` in `anotherFile.ts`:

```
import { doSomethingWithMyDecoratedClasses } from 'myDecorator.ts`
//...
doSomethingWithMyDecoratedClasses()
//...
```

The problem is that I need to make sure that `SomeClass` has been added to `registeredClasses` before I make this call to `doSomethingWithMyDecoratedClasses`.  And, in fact, I've written a number of such classes in my app, and I need to make sure they are all registered.

My current best understanding is that I need to call `import 'someClass.ts'` in `anotherFile.ts` (and, in fact, import *all* files where decorated classes are declared), so really I need to `import someClass1.ts`, `import someClass2.ts`, ...

Is that the best/only approach?  Is there a recommended pattern for doing so?

Comment: Yes, a decorator isn't supposed to help with imports. If you won't import a class that has a decorator, there will be nothing to decorate. So since you need to do imports, you could do them in correct order as well. It may be possible to solve this with async doSomethingWithMyDecoratedClasses but it's a hack that may be inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most applications have an index file that is responsible for importing the top level things. If you import `doSomethingWithMyDecoratedClasses` there, you'll guarantee that everything else is imported first.

An alternative would be to not call it in the root level of a module, and instead wait for an event.